# Keycloak One Time Use token

Tags: keycloak

We have a requirement to generate one time use tokens and use it in password reset emails. 
Does Keycloak provide any standard API´s to generate and Validate one time tokens?.

We are using OIDC 
Rsource Owner Password Credentials Grant (Direct Access Grants for authentication.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement customized Action Token SPI, and Required Action SPI. Which would generate required token and then challenge user for them.

https://www.keycloak.org/docs/7.0/server_development/index.html#_action_token_spi

Comment: Thanks for looking into it. I looked at the Action Token SPI. What i am really missing is how to invoke the SPI to generate and validate the token via REST API calls to Keycloak. Any suggestion on this will be really helpful.  We are using Direct grant with Authentication SPI for login.

Answer (score 0):

[Anatomy of Action Token](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_development/#_action_token_anatomy)

> `nonce` - Random `nonce` to guarantee uniqueness of use if the operation can only be executed once (optional). This is a random string that your application must generate.

> Here’s an example of Java Servlet code that generates the URL to establish the account link.
>
> ```java
> ​KeycloakSecurityContext session = (KeycloakSecurityContext) httpServletRequest.getAttribute(KeycloakSecurityContext.class.getName());
> ​AccessToken token = session.getToken();
> ​String clientId = token.getIssuedFor();
> ​String nonce = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
> ​MessageDigest md = null;
> ​try {
>    ​md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
> ​} catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
>    ​throw new RuntimeException(e);
> ​}
> ​String input = nonce + token.getSessionState() + clientId + provider;
> ​byte[] check = md.digest(input.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
> ​String hash = Base64Url.encode(check);
> ​request.getSession().setAttribute("hash", hash);
> ​String redirectUri = ...;
> ​String accountLinkUrl = KeycloakUriBuilder.fromUri(authServerRootUrl)
>                  ​.path("/auth/realms/{realm}/broker/{provider}/link")
>                  ​.queryParam("nonce", nonce)
>                  ​.queryParam("hash", hash)
>                  ​.queryParam("client_id", clientId)
>                  ​.queryParam("redirect_uri", redirectUri).build(realm, provider).toString();
> ```